# Creation of Classes?

Tags: python, class

I am new in python and trying to figure out how to modularize my functions. My project is a unit testing framework for Restful APIs. For brevity I've simplified the code.

## type_parser.py

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--type', help='a or b')
args = parser.parse_args()

def A(func):
    def return_func():
        if args.type == "b":
          return func()
        else:
          pass
    return return_func

def B(func):
    def return_func():
        if args.type == "a":
          return func()
        else:
          pass
    return return_func
```

## api_funcs.py

```
from type_parser import *

class ApiFunctions:

    @A
    def login():
        print "cool"
    @B
    def logout()
        print "not cool"
```

## main.py

```
from api_funcs import *

api = ApiFunctions()

def __main__():
    api.login()
    api.logout()

__main__()
```

## CLI

```
python main.py --type=a
```

## Outcome

Expected:

```
cool
```

Actual:

```
TypeError: return_func() takes no arguments
```

*It works if I take api functions out of a class and call it straight up, but I would want to make it more abstract since there will be 3 sets of APIs*

## Update - I figured out the answer

```
class ApiFunctions:

    @A
    def login(self):
        print "cool"
    @B
    def logout(self)
        print "not cool"


def A(func):
        def return_func(self):
            if args.type == "b":
              return func(self)
            else:
              pass
        return return_func
```

Comment: Well, `login` and `logout` are methods of `api`, and they're not static methods, so they have at least one argument.....

Comment: There's something missing in your methods. In particular note [What is the purpose of self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you posted your solution as an answer instead of editing your own post

Answer (score 1):

In python the object itself has to be explicitely part of method singature. 
Thus you need to write:
`def login(self):`

Writing `self.login` is *kinda like (*)* writing `login(self)`. Since `login()` takes no argument you get an error.

---

(*) said kinda like, don't write it

---

## api_funcs.py

```
from type_parser import *

class ApiFunctions:

    @A
    def login(self):
        print "cool"
    @B
    def logout(self)
        print "not cool"
```

Comment: Not just there but in the decorated functions as well.

Comment: How would i rewrite my class then

Comment: `login()` and `logout()` are both decorated functions. The decorators return functions that accept no parameters.

Comment: @pltrdy Jeff is right that i have to change something in my decorator would you know how to go about this

Comment: Oh i just found the answer the saw u updated it xD 
Interesting that I never wondered how to actually do it